# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/opencv/core/Core

Tags: java, opencv, noclassdeffounderror

So I added OpenCV in Eclipse in Preferences. Then I tried loading it in Main class and I got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/opencv/core/Core
```